# Regex & Swift: How to suppress all the sub string in a string between two specific strings?

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I try to suppress a sub string in a string between two specific strings, # ************************************************************ and # ------------------------------------------------------------ for example ?

```
...
    # ************************************************************
    # Sequel Pro SQL dump
    # Version 4541
    #
    # http://www.sequelpro.com/
    # https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro
    #
    # Hôte: gmp2.newtelapps.fr (MySQL 5.5.62-0+deb8u1)
    # Base de données: GMP
    # Temps de génération: 2019-01-23 16:27:04 +0000
    # ************************************************************


    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
    /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
    /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;


    # Affichage de la table Table_boolean
    # ------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Other example:
Base string: "12345678<---text to remove--->azertyui"

Result: "12345678azertyui"

I would like to create a function like this:

```
self.removeSubString(inString: Str, fromString:"<---", toString:"--->", includingFromAndToString:YES)
```

That could allow me to erase the exact sub string I want to remove in a string.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I put here the final solution:

```
let result = self.removeSubStringIn(mainStr: str, fromStr: "\\# \\*{60}", toStr: "\\# -{60}", includingFromAndTo: true)

  func removeSubStringIn(mainStr:String, fromStr:String, toStr:String, includingFromAndTo:Bool) -> String?
    {
        var pattern = ""
        if (includingFromAndTo)
        {
            pattern = "(?s)(\(fromStr))(.+?)(\(toStr))"
        }
        else
        {
            pattern = "(?s)(?<=\(fromStr))(.+?)(?=\(toStr))"
        }
        var regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)

        let result = regex!.stringByReplacingMatches(in: mainStr,
                                                     range: NSRange(location: 0, length: mainStr.count),
                                                     withTemplate: "")

        return result
    }
```

Comment: This is unclear. Please update your question by showing a clear example of the input and desired results. Clearly explain what problems you are currently having with your code.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated it

Comment: You need to give a real example. Two or three different real examples would be better. What delimits that text you wish to remove? What's the pattern here?

Comment: @rmaddy I precised it more to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you could remove the word "*World*" preceded by a hashtag which is followed by a space and sixty stars, and followed by a hashtag which is followed by a space and sixty minus signs :

```
let str = "hello# ************************************************************World# ------------------------------------------------------------!"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<=\\# \\*{60}).+?(?=\\# -{60})")

let result = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: str,
                               range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.count),
                               withTemplate: "")

print(result)
```

Which outputs :

> hello# ************************************************************# ------------------------------------------------------------!

The regular expression uses :

- Positive lookbehind `(?<=)`
- Positive lookahead `(?=)`

---

If you'd like to remove the text in the middle too, use the following regex :

```
let regex2 = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\# \\*{60}.+?\\# -{60}")

let result2 = regex2.stringByReplacingMatches(in: str,
                               range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.count),
                               withTemplate: "")

print(result2)  //hello!
```

---

If you want to remove anything between two known strings, then use positive lookbehind and positive lookahead :

```
let str = "12345678<---text to remove--->azertyui"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<=12345678).+?(?=azerty)")

let result = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: str,
                               range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.count),
                               withTemplate: "")

print(result)  //12345678azertyui
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't remove the text in the str string

Comment: @ΩlostA I've updated the answer with an example suited for your updated question

Comment: I don't think that it erase all the occurences in a string, for example if I want to remove all the comments in a string between /* and **/, how can I do it in that string ? "/*aeioaezazeioaizoeu*/ qdsfmlkfdjlmqkdjs/*qsdmfkqsdf*/ qksdjmqklds/*"

Comment: @ΩlostA You keep changing the requirements for the regular expression. Anyway, Try this : `let str = "/*comment1*/ Hello/*comment2*/ World/"; let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "/\\*.+?\\*/")`.